# Vue js Set data after ajax call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a place for displaying user info, when page refreshed i read user info from an ajax call and set user info data.but because of Time-consuming process of axios call Data setup is performed after the DOM rendering.

HTML :

```
<div> {{user.name}} </div>
```

vue.js :

```
data: function(){
 return {
   user: {},
   }
},

methods: { 

getUserInfo() {
   axios.post(laroute.route('link'), data).then((response) => {
      this.$set(this, 'user', response.data.user);
        },
 },

 mounted() {

        this.getUserInfo();
    }
```

after refreshing page i got this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

Comment: `getUserInfo()` should under `methods: { getUserInfo() { ... } }`

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, cannot help you find the reason. and you should check `response.data.user`, maybe is `undefined`

Comment: What is data property in axios.post(laroute.route('link'), data)? Can your please post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @joaner : Both data sent from axios and response data is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant add a comment. You can try to change:

mounted for created
and
this.$set(this, 'user', response.data.user); for user = response.data.user

Anyway, can you console.log the result of call?